# Cant get the method startinfo in system.diagnosis

Tags: c#

```
Error   1   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Process' does not contain a definition for 'StartInfo' and no extension method 'StartInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Process' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
D:\Anas Work\ANAS FOLDER\4th Semester\Introduction To operating System\Programs\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  24  16  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

My code is the following:

```
process p1= new process();
p1.startinfo.filename="chorome.exe";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Habib mentioned in a now-deleted comment, it looks like you've declared your *own* class called `Process`, which is messing things up. I'd recommend renaming that *anyway* just to avoid confusion, but personally I think it's clearest to start a new process by creating the `ProcessStartInfo` first, and then using that to start the process - rather than setting it within an existing `Process` object and then calling `Start`:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "chrome.exe",
    ...
};
var process = Process.Start(info);
```

(Also note that C# is case-sensitive, so your sample code was incorrect on that front too.)

Comment: Jon , I deleted the comment after seeing your answer, because your idea of `ProcessStartInfo` is correct :) - Here is my original comment - Looks like you have your own class `Process` and you are not using [`System.Dignostic.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Comment: @Habib: My answer is fine now, but had some bogus information to start with... your comment was great in terms of working out what was wrong :)

Comment: thanks jon u r right my class name is process so that is why the its create ambiguity for compiler.THANKS once again.anyway how stupid i m.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```